# What does -moz-font-feature-settings: 'kern' do?

Tags: css

I saw at the Apple.com Website that they use

```
-moz-font-feature-settings: 'kern'
```

is this a code for Antialasing?
I cant find anything about it :/

Comment: If you remove the prefix and then search you'll find https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `font-feature-settings` gives you control over advanced typographic features in OpenType fonts. The `-moz-` its Firefox prefix.

Being `kern` for `kerning`, here is a list of the values you can use:

- `liga`: standard ligatures
- `dlig`: discretionary ligatures
- `onum`: old style figures
- `lnum`: lining figures
- `tnum`: tabular figures
- `zero`: slashed zero
- `frac`: fractions
- `sups`: superscript
- `subs`: subscript
- `smcp`: small caps
- `c2sc`: small capitals from capitals
- `case`: case-sensitive forms
- `hlig`: historical ligatures
- `calt`: contextual alternates
- `swsh`: swashes
- `hist`: historical forms
- `ss**`: stylistic sets
- `kern`: kerning
- `locl`: localized forms
- `rlig`: required ligatures
- `medi`: medial forms
- `init`: initial forms
- `isol`: isolated forms
- `fina`: final forms
- `mark`: mark
- `mkmk` mark-to-mark positioning

You can find more info about `font-feature-settings` [**here**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-feature-settings/)